# Angular 2 - How to handle an *ngFor when you want to show "1st", "2nd", "3rd", etc.?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a loop to show a few divs, between one and seven.

However, each div will have a `<p> Pick your 1st photo </p>`, where the first item will say `1st`, the second `2nd`, third `3rd`, etc.

How can I handle something like this?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p>Pick your ___ photo</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just include as a property of an item the text to show?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `index` within `*ngFor` and then transform one-more-than-the-index with an `ordinal` pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <p>Pick your {{ i + 1 | ordinal }} photo</p>
</div>
```

The `ordinal` pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'ordinal'})
export class OrdinalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(int) {
        const ones = +int % 10, tens = +int % 100 - ones;
        return int + ["th","st","nd","rd"][ tens === 10 || ones > 3 ? 0 : ones ];
    }
}
```

[@Brad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480564/5218951) and comment gives the critical information about the *ngFor `index`. This answer expands on that, providing a pipe to transform a number (specifically, one more than the index) into the appropriate ordinal-suffix-containing-string, e.g. converting `2` to `"2nd"`. Note that `i` is incremented before the pipe because `index` is 0-based while ordinals are 1-based.

Comment: I'm not going to expand my answer because I feel it already answers the question but perhaps you could expand your answer to implement this functionality using a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

`*ngFor` has an `index` variable that you can access in the loop as explained in the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
  <p>Pick your {{ i + 1 }} photo</p>
</div>
```

From this you should be able to figure out how to display 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I read the documentation.  How does the index work though?  Is that some variable that I need in my component.ts?

Comment: The `index` variable is in the `ngFor` directive and is incremented on each iteration.  You can only access it when writing your expression - note the `let i = index;` part of my answer - this sets a variable `i` to the current value of `index` which you can then use within the scope of the for loop in your template.  You don't need to define anything in your component.